# Very slow 3G internet connection on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: internet

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on Dell laptop. I connected a phone with 3G connection to the laptop using bluetooth for internet. The net is very slow...How can I fix this?? It was pretty fast on windows

Comment: wait... what you stated in here is 3G tethering, not Dialup.  Which is it?  (Dialup is where you have to have your computer dial a phone number in order to connect to an internet server, and has been pretty sparsely seen in the USA since about 2000 :/)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is the bluetooth, data transfer via bluetooth is very slow. If the function is available, use USB or better still if your phone is a smartphone, set up a portable wi-fi hotspot. I hope this helps.